# MAP inference in Bipartite Bayesian Network?

Tags: bayesian-network

I have a set of $n+\binom{n}{2}$ random variables $\{x_i\}^{i=n}_{i=1}\cup \{x_{ij}\}_{i\leq j}$ and their probability distribution is given as:
$$P(x_1,...,x_n,x_{12},...,x_{ij},...x_{nn}) = \prod_{i}P(x_i)\prod_{i\leq j}P(x_{ij}|x_i,x_j)$$
Now, this can be represented as a bipartite Bayesian Network with the following repeated pattern for all $i \leq j$ :
$$x_i \rightarrow x_{ij}\leftarrow{x_j}$$

Are there any efficient algorithms for MAP inference in this set up?  In other words, I have evidence on the state of some of the random variables and not on others; can I estimate the most probable state of the rest of the variables efficiently ?